# Anyone understand why this query no longer works?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query

On Localhost this query works correctly, running normal MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as rows, customers. * 
FROM customers 
WHERE user_id = 6 
      AND age = 10 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0
```

However on the latest mariadb it throws up this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as rows, customers. * 
FROM customers 
WHERE user_id = 6 
      AND age = 10 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'rows, customers. * FROM customers WHERE user_id = 6 AND age' at line 1
>   Time: 0.011s

Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: Is this a real question? I have no idea what you mean by "it works correctly" but the query is useless.

Answer (score 5):

`rows` is a reserved keyword in MariaDB.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/

Unless you single- or double- or backquote it:

```
select id as 'rows' from tbl;
select id as "rows" from tbl;
select id as `rows` from tbl;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=466dadd5f915cbe242172a7bda83d8ae)*

As commented by [dbdemon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/94242/dbdemon), `rows` is now a reserved word in MySQL too, specifically [starting from version 8.0.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R). See another db<>fiddle demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=466dadd5f915cbe242172a7bda83d8ae).